# How can I debug a .jar library source code imported in my unit testing project?

Tags: debugging, blackberry, unit-testing, jar

I'm working on a Blackberry application (JDE 4.6.1 + Windows machine + Elipse). Currently my workspace involves two main project

- Unit testing application (called unitT)
- my application (calle myApp)

Basically,I compile the myApp project in a .jar file and I import this as a library in the uniT project (so I can reference it). The problem is that it's not possible debugging the code in the .jar file. 
If,during the execution in debug mode,I step into the library code, Eclipse asks me to indicate the source forlder (in my case myApp/src)..at this point the source code linked to the myApp.jar library appears but,even if I place a breakpoint into it,this is totally useless since the debugger would never enter into it (and he should).

Any ideas?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions

1) You can build a second jar containing the sources of your app. Then you say your IDE that the source of your jar are in the other jar (source linkage)

2) You can set up some project dependencies instead of jar dependencies, (at least this is possible in Eclipse, but should be in another IDE)